# Jenkins - How to add a predefined paramter into the strem selector

Tags: jenkins, clearcase, jenkins-plugins, clearcase-ucm

I'm using in some builds the UCM ClearCase option (Source Code Mamagement)
I have to input the view tag, view path and the stream selector. How can i put a parameter inside the stream selector instead of the stream itself. 
For example: now i have in the stream selector: `RavenApp2.0.0.0_Integ@/vobs/tlv_pvob`
I want to put a parameter instead the RavenApp2.0.0.0 some like this `${project}_Integ@/vobs/tlv_pvob`
The thing is that it's not reading the value of this parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the [ClearCase UCM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin) code includes substituting variables (like `${project}`) in the "`Stream`" field, the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3502786/user3502786) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343739/jenkins-how-to-add-a-predefined-paramter-into-the-strem-selector/26355036?noredirect=1#comment41369903_26355036):

> I've solved it by adding a `STREAM` variable to the build properties, then I've inserted this parameter `${STREAM}` to the `Stream` field, and read the value inside.

---

Another approach would be to use a:

- parameter with the baseline you want to use for that job
- dedicated integration stream (that you can rebase at will)
- a pre-build step which would rebase that stream with said baseline, and update your UCM view

Comment: So i've solved it by adding a `STREAM` variable to the build properties, then i've inserted this parameter `${STREAM}` to the stream field, and read the value inside.

Comment: @user3502786 Great! I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.